# what does the at sign before a dollar sign @$VAR do in a SED string in a Shell script?

Tags: shell, sed

What does `@$VAR` mean in Shell? I don't get the use of `@` in this case.

I encountered the following shell file while working on my dotfiles repo

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

KEY="$1"
VALUE="$2"
FILE="$3"

touch "$FILE"

if grep -q "$1=" "$FILE"; then
  sed "s@$KEY=.*@$KEY=\"$VALUE\"@" -i "$FILE"
else
  echo "export $KEY=\"$VALUE\"" >> "$FILE"
fi
```

and I'm struggling with understanding the `sed "s@$KEY=.*@$KEY=\"$VALUE\"@" -i "$FILE"` line, especially the use of `@`.

Comment: I'm not able to distinguish if this is SED specific or Shell specific, thus the two tags.

Comment: `sed` supports multiple separators from the traditional `/` in `s/old/new/`. You could custom delimiters of choice, if you think `/` is part of your string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `sed` you must not necessarily use a `/` character as the delimiter for the `substitute` action.

Thereby, the `@`, or `%` characters are also perfectly fine options to be used instead:

```
echo A | sed s/A/B/
echo A | sed s@A@B@
echo A | sed s%A%B%
```

Comment: Aha, so this is just a case of "I grabbed the separator I suppose never will be used in my strings"? Makes sense! Thanks dude :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the command

```
sed "s@$KEY=.*@$KEY=\"$VALUE\"@" -i "$FILE"
```

the character `@` is used as a delimiter in the `s` command of `sed`. The general form of the `s` (substitute) command is

```
s<delim><searchPattern><delim><replaceString><delim>[<flags>]
```

where the most commonly used <delim> is `/`, but other characters are sometimes used, especially when either <searchPattern> or <replaceString> contain (or might contain) slashes.